# Why two-step encryption on secure document transfer?

Tags: encryption, webcrypto-api

I read a section in a W3C article (https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#protected-document) on Web Cryptography API. It went like this,

> **Protected Document Exchange:**
> A web application may wish to limit the viewership of documents that
> contain sensitive or personal information, even when these documents
> have been securely received, such as over TLS.
>
> Using the Web Cryptography API, the application could do so by
> encrypting the documents with a secret key, and then wrapping that key
> with the public keys associated with the authorized viewers. When a
> user agent navigates to such a web application, the application would
> send the encrypted form of the document. The user agent is then
> instructed to unwrap the encryption key, using the user's private key,
> and from there, decrypt and display the document.

I'm wondering, why that double step of encrypting the document with a secret key first and then wrapping the secret key with users' public keys? Isn't just encrypting the document with users' public keys and sending over enough? Or, is it done just to get the performance benefit of not having to encrypt the document separately for each user?

Comment: Data is typically not encrypted with public keys, that is a misconception that non-experts have. The standard approach uses [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), which is what your quote is describing. Hybrid encryption is simpler to secure and much, much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Public Key cryptosystems are slow compared to symmetric cryptosystems. Therefore we prefer [the hybrid approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem); key exchange with public key cryptosystem and data is encrypted with the exchanged key. Here some ways;

- Use Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange (DHKE) to derive a session key. Use a KDF like HKDF to derive the desired key and encrypt with a symmetric algorithm with a good mode of operations like AES-GCM and ChaCha20-1204 ( Both in TLS 1.3.).

  With this, you will have the forward secrecy with DHKE and confidentiality, integrity, and authentication with AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305.

  Preferable use Elliptic Curve version of DHKE named ECDH.
- Use RSA-KEM for Key Encapsulation. Select a random in the modulus range, again use HKDF to derive the key, and again use AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305 to encrypt, send the key with RSA encryption, and ciphertext together.

This is the gist of Key Encapsulation Mechanism (KEM) and Data Encapsulation Mechanism (DEM).